# Reference Warning in Xcode 8.0

Tags: objective-c, reference, xcode8

I had deleted few files earlier which was not used for the application from Xcode and I updated this to Xcode 8, but now it is showing reference warning at time of build.

I tried to delete derived data from project setting but still it is showing the same. Attaching the screenshot as well. Please share solution for this.

[image]